# Searching across a Table Removes Paging

Tags: jquery

I have a Table and have implemented some paging. The Paging works just fine!

I have also added a text field so that the user can search a column. This is the logic used

```
$( "input#filter" ).keyup( function() {
    var filtertext = $( this ).val();
    $( "#movie tbody tr" ).each( function( rowindex ) {
        $( this ).children( "td" ).eq( 2 ).each( function( cellindex ) {
            if ( $( this ).text().indexOf( filtertext ) < 0 ) {
                $( this ).parents( "tr" ).hide();
            } else {
                $( this ).parents( "tr" ).show();
            }
        });
    });
})
```

But whenever the user types the first character in the textbox, the paging goes for a toss and all rows are visible again. How can I fix the bug?

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Pja65/

**P.S:** I am not using any plugin as I have a simple requirement and don't want to use any plugin for it

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pja65/1/
You have more than 2-3 bugs there.
1. `$( this ).children( "td" ).eq( 2 )` should be `$( this ).children( "td" ).eq( 1 )`. It is getting the third column.
2. You need to check if the search term is null, if yes, show all the rows, by calling `paginate(firstRecord, pageSize);`.

```
$( "input#filter" ).keyup( function() {
var filtertext = $( this ).val();
if(filtertext != '')
    $( "#movie tbody tr" ).each( function( rowindex ) {
        $( this ).children( "td" ).eq( 1 )
            .each( function( cellindex ) {
                if ( $( this ).text().indexOf( filtertext ) < 0 ) {
                    $( this ).parents( "tr" ).hide();
                } else {
                    $( this ).parents( "tr" ).show();
                }
            });
    });
else
    paginate(firstRecord, pageSize);
})
```

Comment: I observed a couple of things. If I type "1", the next page is shown whereas "1" is present on the first page too. Typing 1968 produces no rows whereas 4 rows should come up